# Where is a[0] pointing at?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Let's say we have an array `char a[] = "abcd"`. When I print the following:

```
printf("%p\n", a);
printf("%p\n", &a);
printf("%p\n", &a[0]);
printf("%p\n", a[0]);
```

I am getting the following results:

```
0061FF1B
0061FF1B
0061FF1B
00000061
```

which means that `a[0]` is not pointing at the same memory address as either `%a[0]` or `a`. This is really confusing to me. I'd like someone to *point* out the **difference** between these pointers, and whether or not `a[0]` **is** / **decays** to a pointer.

Comment: The `a[0]` in the last output is not "pointing" to *any* memory address. It is the data value of the first element. `a[0]` and `&a[0]` are different things. But `printf("%p\n", a[0]);` is *undefined behaviour*. The `%p` expects a type of `(void*)` to be passed, but you passed `char`.

Comment: `a[0]` is of type `char`, so you cannot use `%p` as a format specifier. `a[0]` is indeed not a memory address at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char a[] = "abcd"
```

1. Array `a`, when used in an expression, will convert to pointer to first element of array i.e. `&a[0]` (there are few *[exceptions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)* to this rule).
2. `&a` is address of array `a` which is numerically same as the address of first element of array `&a[0]` but the difference is in their type. The type of `&a[0]` is `char *` whereas the type of `&a` is `char (*) [5]`.
3. `&a[0]` is address of first element of array `a`.
4. `a[0]` is first element of character array `a`.

> which means that a[0] is not pointing at the same memory address as either %a[0] or a. ..........
> whether or not a[0] is / decays to a pointer.

`a[0]` is not a pointer, it is first element of array `a` which is character `'a'`. Note that decay happens when array name is used.

When printing `a[0]`, you should use the format specifier `%c`. Wrong format specifier in `printf()` lead to undefined behaviour. Also, format specifier `%p` expect that the argument shall be a pointer to `void`. You should type cast pointer argument to `void *` - `printf("%p\n", (void*)a);`.

Answer (score 2):

`a[0]` is not pointing anywhere because it isn't a pointer but a `char` object. You lie to `printf` and tell it that it is a pointer, when it isn't. That's an undefined behavior bug in your program.

Now as it happens 0x61 is the ASCII code for `'a'`.

---

Regarding the other lines in your code: whenever used in expressions or function calls, arrays "decay" into a pointer to their first element. There are very few exceptions when this decay doesn't happen - using the `&` address-of operator is one of them.

Therefore: `printf("%p\n", a);` decays to a pointer to the first element, which is 100% equivalent to `printf("%p\n", &a[0]);`.

In case of `printf("%p\n", &a);` the decay does not happen but you get the address of the array itself. In C, an array is nothing but a bunch of elements with no other overhead, so the address of the array will always be the same as the address of the first element.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile the code with g++, you will find the following warning

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:21: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("%p\n", a[0]);
           ~~~~^
```

Here, `a` and &a[0] point to the address of first item of the string
while a[0] is a char. You print a[0] whose ascii is `0x00000061` with `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%p\n", &a[0]);
printf("%p\n", a[0]);
```

In the first case you correctly print the address of the first element of `a`.

In the second case you ask printf to print a pointer but you pass it a `char`.

The char is [automatically converted to an int](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (due to the signature of printf, that contains `...`).

> The  ellipsis  notation  in  a  function  prototype  declarator
> causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared
> parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing
> arguments

The fact that printf prints `61` (exactly the ASCII code) is because on your computer the pointer to object and the `int` have the same number of bits or because it has `0`s next to integer, where printf reads the pointer value.

But it is undefined behavior to pass printf a type and instrument it print other type.

Answer (score 0):

In C array variable is like address

```
char a[] = "abcd";
// it is all same
// a == &a == &a[0]
// &(a + 1) == &a[1]
// so roughly say 'a' is pointer to address of first element of array
// and a[0] or a[1] is a value.
// this is more appropriate way to express a[0]
printf("%c\n", a[0]);
```

Comment: Change `%s` to `%c` in your last `printf()`: `a[0]` is of type `char`, not `char*`.

Comment: but I also curious why the output of a[0] as address is 00000061 but not 97(as ascii).

Comment: 1) The format specifier `%p` is implementation-defined (i.e.: it has not a required particular representation), however it appears that most platforms use hexadecimal notation for `%p`, and `0x61` is indeed `97`; 2) It is still not guaranteed as `%p` expects a value of type `void*`, that has (usually) a different size than `char`; 3) TL;DR: lucky result, mixed with undefined behavior.

Comment: @TaekYoung: 61 is the hexa for 97...

Comment: Thanks...  "0x61" equals 97